# Buffer to JSON requires parsing twice. Hyperledger Fabric v1.4 Node.js Chaincode

Tags: node.js, json, hyperledger-fabric

This is the chaincode (Node.js), which returns the JSON PO as Buffer to the Fabric Middleware (Node SDK)

```
    async queryPo(ctx, poNumber) {
    const poAsBytes = await ctx.stub.getState(poNumber); // get the po from chaincode state
    if (!poAsBytes || poAsBytes.length === 0) {
        throw new Error(`${poNumber} does not exist`);
    }
    console.info(poAsBytes.toString());
    return poAsBytes.toString();
}
```

getState reference: [Hyperledger Fabric Node.js Chaincode Doc](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getState__anchor)

This is the Middleware Code,

```
async function queryOneRO(roid, userID, channelID) {
    try {
        const myresult = await getContract(userID, channelID);
        const contract = myresult.contract;
        const result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('queryRo', roid);
        const gateway = myresult.gateway;
        gateway.disconnect();
        const data = (JSON.parse(result.toString()));
        if (data.docType === "ro") {
            console.log("data1", data);
            return data;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        return '{"status":"Failed to evaluate the transaction' + error + '"}';
    }
}
```

Which requires dual JSON.parse, inorder to work:

```
 const data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(result.toString()));
            if (data.docType === "ro") {
                console.log("data1", data);
                return data;
            }
```

Here are the sample results of each step:

**result:**

```
< Buffer 22 7b 5c 22 41 6d 6e ... >
```

**result.toString():**

```
"{\"AmndType\":\"\",\"docType\":\"ro\"}"
```

**JSON.parse(result.toString()):**

```
{"AmndType":"","docType":"ro"}
```

**JSON.parse(JSON.parse(result.toString())):**

```
 { AmndType: '',
     docType: 'ro' }
```

This is where JSON.parse is required twice. Why?

The Dev Environment is : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS, Hyperledger v1.4, Node.js v10.16.3, GOlang:1.12.9

> During deployment in different environment with same software & OS
>   stack as above, except GOlang:1.11.x, the JSON.parse is not needed
>   twice. We had to remove all the second JSON.parse ().  Why?

Comment: How have you declared your software dependencies for your smart contract ? ie what does your package json look like ?

Comment: @david_k Here it is:   "dependencies": {
    "fabric-contract-api": "^1.4.1",
    "fabric-shim": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0"
  }

Comment: from that package.json, it's not clear that you are using the same versions of dependencies between the 2 deployments, unless you have explicitly provided a `shrinkwrap.json` as part of your package to guarantee this. I suspect that you are in fact running different versions of dependencies in your smart contract between the deployments. The one at the newer levels will only require a single JSON.parse.

Comment: Thank you @david_k. I will check and get back

Comment: Hi @david_k, You are right, I changed the dependencies from 1.4.1 to 1.4.2, "dependencies": { "fabric-contract-api": "^1.4.2", "fabric-shim": "^1.4.2" }, works fine with Single JSON.parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, @david_d mentioned above in comments, it is the issue with the dependencies in Chaincode. We have to use 1.4.2 and above 
`"dependencies": { "fabric-contract-api": "^1.4.2", "fabric-shim": "^1.4.2" }` instead `"dependencies": { "fabric-contract-api": "^1.4.1", "fabric-shim": "^1.4.1" }` in `package.json`